# How to draw the linear regression curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, curve

I have just started learning `Python` and am wondering how I can draw the linear regression curve with **time series** of price data(for example, close prices, which has **only y factors**)

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

start=datetime(2015,1,1)
end=datetime(2015,12,31)

df = web.DataReader("AMZN", "yahoo", start, end)
close = df['Close']
```

I referred to this [web page](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/charting/thinkscript/reference/Functions/Statistical/Inertia.html) to grasp the basic idea of drawing the linear regression curve, but I don't know what functions to use to write it again in `python`.

Comment: Please clarify if you ask an advice on _calculating_ the regression coefficients or _drawing_ the regression line with known coefficients.

Comment: I'm sorry for my vague question. The ultimate goal is to draw the linear regression curve that shows the trend of stock price like this(http://www.onlinetradingconcepts.com/TechnicalAnalysis/LinRegCurve.html) but I can't find any formula related to it, so I'm wondering how to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm

start = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2015, 12, 31)

df = web.DataReader("AMZN", "yahoo", start, end)

df['day'] = df.index.map(lambda observation_timestamp: observation_timestamp.dayofyear)
y = df.Close
X = df.day
X = sm.add_constant(X)
est = sm.OLS(y, X)
est = est.fit()

X_prime = np.linspace(X.day.min(), X.day.max(), 100)
X_prime = sm.add_constant(X_prime)
y_hat = est.predict(X_prime)

plt.plot(X_prime[:,1], y_hat)
plt.scatter(X.day, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

execute this `est.summary()`:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  Close   R-squared:                       0.935
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.934
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     3570.
Date:                Mon, 05 Dec 2016   Prob (F-statistic):          5.06e-150
Time:                        00:27:53   Log-Likelihood:                -1199.8
No. Observations:                 252   AIC:                             2404.
Df Residuals:                     250   BIC:                             2411.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const        289.9491      3.622     80.053      0.000       282.816   297.083
day            1.0212      0.017     59.748      0.000         0.988     1.055
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       15.313   Durbin-Watson:                   0.117
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):                6.134
Skew:                           0.007   Prob(JB):                       0.0466
Kurtosis:                       2.236   Cond. No.                         429.
==============================================================================
```

another example:

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime
import statsmodels.api as sm
from patsy.highlevel import dmatrices

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = datetime(2015, 12, 31)

df = web.DataReader("AMZN", "yahoo", start, end)

df['day'] = df.index.map(lambda observation_timestamp: observation_timestamp.dayofyear)

y, X = dmatrices('Close ~ day', data=df, return_type='dataframe')

mod = sm.OLS(y, X)

res = mod.fit()
sm.stats.linear_rainbow(res)
sm.graphics.plot_regress_exog(res, "day")
plt.show()
```

[image]

changed `sm.graphics.plot_regress_exog(res, "day")` to `sm.graphics.plot_fit(res, "day")`

[image]

execute this: `res.summary()`

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  Close   R-squared:                       0.935
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.934
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     3570.
Date:                Mon, 05 Dec 2016   Prob (F-statistic):          5.06e-150
Time:                        00:26:04   Log-Likelihood:                -1199.8
No. Observations:                 252   AIC:                             2404.
Df Residuals:                     250   BIC:                             2411.
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept    289.9491      3.622     80.053      0.000       282.816   297.083
day            1.0212      0.017     59.748      0.000         0.988     1.055
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       15.313   Durbin-Watson:                   0.117
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):                6.134
Skew:                           0.007   Prob(JB):                       0.0466
Kurtosis:                       2.236   Cond. No.                         429.
==============================================================================
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May I ask you one more question? The plots you show me are all linear(ax). Do you happen to know how to draw a linear regression line that curves and follows price change? (For exampe, like this: http://www.onlinetradingconcepts.com/images/technicalanalysis/LinRegCurveES.gif)